# Manipulate variables containing quoted strings in a BASH script

Tags: string, bash, variables, spaces, double-quotes

I have to pass a variable like `data='Type=Eatable Fruits="Apple Orange"'` to a bash script (print.sh) that simply print the first, second, than third command line argument, one by line.

When I passed the variable `data` to the script, by running: `sh print.sh $data`, the output was

```
Type=Eatable
Fruits="Apple
Orange"
```

But then need was

```
Type=Eatable
Fruits="Apple Orange"
```

The second line should also print double-quotes. ( Third argument should be NULL/Nothing )

What should I change to get output like above?

Answer (score 2):

When you run `sh print.sh $data`, it gets tokenized like this:

[`sh`, `print.sh`, `$data`]

Because `$data` is not quoted, the value of the variable `data` gets tokenized to

[`Fruits="Apple`, `Orange"`]

Which is then added to the original command to make

[`sh`, `print.sh`, `Fruits="Apple`, `Orange"`]

And `print.sh` gets called with $1=`Fruits="Apple`, $2=`Orange"`

It sounds like you actually wanted this to be one parameter to `print.sh`, not two. Using `"$data"` instead of `$data` will make this happen, as per Pierre-Louis Laffont's answer

Answer (score 1):

Make your call with you variable between double quotes :

```
$ ./script.sh $data
Fruits="Apple
Orange"

$ ./script.sh "$data"  
Fruits="Apple Orange"
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents, script will need modification. Are you using

```
echo $1
echo $2
```

you should try

```
echo $1 $2
```

When you passed the string I suspect that everything was taken as arg1 and arg2 was empty. Confirm by printing $#.